# Obtaining total population using Taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I want to use formula
$$P(M)=\int_{0}^{M}\left[2\pi x D(x) \right]dx$$

to calculate total population living within a mile. We are given
$$D(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+0.5x^{2}}$$
Now the question first asked to obtain the $6$th degree polynomial of $2\pi x D(x)$, so first obtained the $6$th degree polynomial for
$$\dfrac{1}{1+0.5x^{2}}$$
and got
$$\dfrac{1}{1+0.5x^{2}}=1-\dfrac{1}{2}x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}x^{4}-\dfrac{1}{8}x^{6}$$

then I did this:
$$2\pi x D(x)=2\pi x \bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{2}x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}x^{4}-\dfrac{1}{8}x^{6} \bigg) $$

and got
$$2\pi x D(x)=1000\pi \bigg[ x - \dfrac{1}{2}x^{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}x^{5}-\dfrac{1}{8}x^{7} \bigg]$$

so now when I wanted to calculate the population within one mile I get:
\begin{align*}
 P(1)=1000\pi \int_{0}^{1} \bigg[ x - \dfrac{1}{2}x^{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}x^{5}-\dfrac{1}{8}x^{7} \bigg] \; dx =1259
\end{align*}

which I think is wrong. The answer is supposed to be $13090$, from a solution manual this was the answer:
\begin{align*}
 P(1)=1000\pi \int_{0}^{1} \bigg[ x - \dfrac{1}{2}x^{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}x^{5}\bigg] \; dx =13090
\end{align*}

notice that the term $-\dfrac{1}{8}x^{7}$ is missing, which I don't understand why. The question asked to obtain the $6th$ degree polynomial for $2\pi x D(x)$ and the manual wrote:
$$2\pi x D(x)=1000\pi \bigg[ x - \dfrac{1}{2}x^{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}x^{5} \bigg]$$

why did we eliminate the $-\dfrac{1}{8}x^{7}$ term? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you want a *6th* degree polynomial approximation of $xD(x)$, which should not contain the $x^7$ term.

Otherwise, you get a polynomial of degree $7$ for $xD(x)$.

---

Notes.

"the question first asked to obtain the 6th degree polynomial of $2()$", not a 6th degree polynomial of $D(x)$.